# SAS editor window position

Tags: layout, sas

This is not quite a programming question, but SAS programmers might still know an answer: It is possible to make SAS save the settings after shutdown, so the window arrangement will be the same after a restart. We have SAS running on a Server but this feature still works.

SAS 9.3 TS Level 1M2      ("Base SAS")

X64_S08R2Windows NT Server-Version

Windows-Version 6.1.7601

After starting SAS there appears an "editor" window at the position where it was before the last SAS-shutdown.

Now the problem is that when opening a second empty editor window (or when I open another SAS program via the SAS menu) this new editor window does NOT appear at the position where I want it to appear -- i.e. at the same place where the first editor window has been aligned to.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: You're using DM ('base SAS', shortcut is a triangle with a yellow stripe across it)?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the post. Yes, it is "Base SAS". Don't know what "DM" means in this respect, though.

Comment: DM="display manager" and is a name for the GUI . I am fairly certain that there is no way to save the position of additional editor windows. I agree that it would be much more convenient if there were.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if more recent versions of SAS improved on this regard, but in any case, here are a few workarounds:

- Use the `tilev` (SHIFT-F4) and `tileh` (SHIFT-F3) commands when appropriate. You can minimize unwanted windows and repeat to have only, say, your editor and your log tiled.
- Assign `wdef` commands to keys (F9) for predefined window positions/sizes. For example, I use these (which are ok on a wide screen with docked explorer on -- tweak the values to your needs):

  **F4:**  wdef 1 1 100 113
  **F5:**   wdef 1 114 100 120

When I open an existing program (or create a new one), I just press F4 so that the wpgm (editor window) uses roughly 2 thirds of the avaiable space. Then if needed, I activate the log and press F5. The editor and the log are now side-by-side as I want them.

Comment: This is even better than saving the location of a window! I also religiously organise my windows layout before closing SAS, but when I accidentally resize the "docked" side box, everything is messed up and I have to put everything back. This way I just hit "Alt+F2" for left and "Alt+F3" for right window.